# How we can filter a treeview using textbox or comboBox

Tags: c#, xml

I load an Xml file in a treeview , then I want to filter this treeview.
I have a textbox and treeview in C# windows form application. What i want to do is , due to the text data entered in the textbox, the treeview will automatically locate to the entered data dynamically. While i'm  typing , the treeview will refresh itself with only the matching nodes with the criteria entered. ( maybe with combo box also )

```
  void fieldFilterTxtBx_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

this.fieldsTree.BeginUpdate(); if (this.fieldFilterTxtBx.Text !=string.Empty)
{
foreach (TreeNode _parentNode in _fieldsTreeCache.Nodes)
{
    foreach (TreeNode _childNode in _parentNode.Nodes)
    {
        if (_childNode.Text.StartsWith(this.fieldFilterTxtBx.Text))
        {
            this.fieldsTree.Nodes.Add((TreeNode)_childNode.Clone());
        }
    }
}
```

}
else
{

thank u for help

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoveflow, its not working like that you need to show what you have tried or a sample of your code so people could help you.

Comment: @Santo do you want to focus on the match tree node?

Comment: I did not understand?? in fact I tried to create a tree to make a copy, but it does not work